# acer e5-573g wi-fi adapter not working

Tags: wireless, acer

`sudo lshw -class network`

```
*-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 15
       serial: 2c:60:0c:9f:61:e1
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.1.5 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:48 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:c4404000-c4404fff memory:c4400000-c4403fff


*-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Qualcomm Atheros
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 30
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:c4200000-c43fffff
```

`ifconfig -a`

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 2c:60:0c:9f:61:e1  
          inet addr:192.168.1.5  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fd08:7a4c:2341:9900:51df:7545:f74a:a09a/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fd08:7a4c:2341:9900:2e60:cff:fe9f:61e1/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::2e60:cff:fe9f:61e1/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:27975 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:22994 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:28221439 (28.2 MB)  TX bytes:2962035 (2.9 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:3360 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3360 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:485402 (485.4 KB)  TX bytes:485402 (485.4 KB)
```

`lspci -knn`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Host Bridge -OPI [8086:1604] (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:098a]
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics [8086:1606] (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:098a]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
00:03.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller [8086:160c] (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:098a]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB xHCI Controller [8086:9cb1] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:098a]
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP MEI Controller #1 [8086:9cba] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:098a]
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller [8086:9ca0] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:098a]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 [8086:9c90] (rev e3)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1c.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #3 [8086:9c94] (rev e3)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1c.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #4 [8086:9c96] (rev e3)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1c.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 [8086:9c98] (rev e3)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB EHCI Controller [8086:9ca6] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:098a]
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP LPC Controller [8086:9cc5] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:098a]
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] [8086:9c83] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:098a]
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SMBus Controller [8086:9ca2] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:098a]
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:098a]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
**03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0042] (rev 30)**
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc Device [11ad:0806]
04:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:1299] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:098b]
    Kernel driver in use: nouveau
```

Comment: @DavidFoerster There is no WindowsXP driver for this adapter and it is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

These are now working thanks to the work of Bartosz Markowski and his kernel patch and the testing by dr-cono

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r) git
echo "options ath10k_core skip_otp=y" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath10k_core.conf
wget http://filebin.ca/2LVgpjSgiT56/backports-ath-2015-11-05.tar.bz2
unzip backports-ath-2015-11-05.tar.bz2
cd backports-ath10k-2015-11-05
make defconfig-ath10k
make
sudo make install
git clone https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware.git
sudo cp -r ath10k-firmware/ath10k/ /lib/firmware/
sudo cp -r ath10k-firmware/QCA9377 /lib/firmware/ath10k/
cp firmware-5.bin_WLAN.TF.1.0-00267-1 firmware-5.bin
```

Reboot

Edit: There has been a recent change to the kvalo github site and the 
`sudo cp -r ath10k-firmware/ath10k/ /lib/firmware/` is no longer valid or needed