# Wireless lan QCA61x4 not working on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, firmware

I've installed Ubuntu 15.10 on my laptop(Samsung NT900X3K-K78S)
Everything works fine except wireless lan(QCA61x4). So, I've searched and tried every related question answers. but there is no working solution. how can I resolve this problem?

**uname -a**

```
Linux 900X3K 4.2.0-18-generic #22-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 6 18:25:50 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**ifconfig -a**

```
enp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 98:83:89:10:ec:be  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1324 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1324 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:101763 (101.7 KB)  TX bytes:101763 (101.7 KB)
```

**lspci | grep QCA**

```
01:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 20)
```

**lsmod | grep ath**

```
(empty)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/674662/acer-e5-573g-wi-fi-adapter-not-working/695256#695256)

Answer (score 0):

PROBLEM SOLVED!

**Note that** I confirmed following solution works on linux 4.2; perior kernel may not works.

This is how I accomplished:

1. Download firmware: https://github.com/makerj/ath10k-firmware/archive/master.zip
2. Unzip archive
3. WE NEED **board.bin**, **firmware-5.bin_SW_RM~** which placed at QCA6174/hw2.1. thus, copy directory from ./ath10k-firmware-master/QCA6174 to /lib/firmware/ath10k

   `sudo cp -r ./ath10k-firmware-master/QCA6174 /lib/firmware/ath10k`
4. **Remove** any **suffix** from firmware file. (e.g. firmware-5.bin_SW_RM~. to firmware-5.bin)
5. Reboot

Code version:

```
wget https://github.com/makerj/ath10k-firmware/archive/master.zip
unzip master.zip
cd ath10k-firmware-master/
sudo cp -r QCA6174/ /lib/firmware/ath10k/
cd /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/
sudo mv firmware-5.bin_SW_RM.1.1.1-00157-QCARMSWPZ-1 firmware-5.bin
sudo reboot
```